# What would cause NVMe throttling on a brss as nd new system?

Tags: ssd, storage, nvme

I’ve got two brand new Samsung 980 Pro NVMes installed on a brand new server board. The problem is, something seems to be throttling their performance at odd times.

Here is what I sometimes get good random performance:

[image: good random perf]

Thr problem is, other times I get bad random performance:

[image: bad random perf]

On exactly th same system, exact same level of activity.

Where can I start troubleshooting. What is responsible for performance on NVMes?

Here is the disk info on the drive:

[image: Drive Info]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could be overheating. Does your SSD have a heat spreader on it?

Comment: it does not. but as the temperature sensor shows, it's not very hot. could there be temps that are too high that are not reported?

also, the board is in the open room, and the system is idle when i run the test. should it be throttling itself at 55C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i can tell it was the power policy that was throttling it in the BIOS. changed it to performance and now they're flying :)